# AES instruction Is Disable in My VPS | How Software-Based Implementation Of AES In CentOS 7

Tags: centos, openvpn, bios

My VPS is CENTOS 7.
I installed OpenVPN on this vps.
After open it's admin panel i received this error :

> AES instruction set support has not been detected on this host. This
> may cause performance degradation. Consult your virtualization
> solution and/or BIOS/UEFI setting to enable AES instructions.

It seems the owner of server has disabled `AES instruction` via `BIOS/UEFI setting`.
I asked them about it and they told we did n't change anything.
I reinstalled os and faced that error again.
How can i enable `AES instruction` again `Software-Based` on CentOS 7?

---

**//Here is cpu info of that vps after comment//**

**cat /proc/cpuinfo**

```
processor : 0
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model : 13
model name : QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
stepping : 3
microcode : 0x1
cpu MHz : 2593.910
cache size : 16384 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 1
core id : 0
cpu cores : 1
apicid : 0
initial apicid : 0
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp : yes
flags : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips : 5187.82
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor : 1
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model : 13
model name : QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
stepping : 3
microcode : 0x1
cpu MHz : 2593.910
cache size : 16384 KB
physical id : 1
siblings : 1
core id : 0
cpu cores : 1
apicid : 1
initial apicid : 1
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp : yes
flags : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good nopl xtopology eagerfpu pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips : 5187.82
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Without information about the CPU, it is not possible to answer your question. It might simply be that the CPU does not support it. Post a section of the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: Hello!!!!! Is any body home here?